# how can i obtain an entire element from an external page?

Tags: php, jquery

how can i get a

```
<table class="precios">
```

from another url (www.example.com) in HTML format?? because with DOM i can obtain the table but in an array mode.

Thank you everyone for helping

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the document from another URL and scrape out the desired `<table>` element?

Comment: i want to get that table and save it in an HTML document...

Comment: i have to parse it to HTML again...

Comment: Do you want a solution in PHP or jQuery? I'm unsure.

Comment: @Jack how can avoid this warnings from the page?? happens in $doc->loadHTMLFile(

Notice: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Namespace prefix fb is not defined

Comment: @cola89 Updated answer .. you have to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` and clear the errors after you're done parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no cross-domain issues, you can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for that:

```
$container.load('http://www.example.com/path/to/page table.precios');
```

Whereby `$container` is a jQuery object where you want to "save" the table into.

Within PHP you would solve it this way:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$table = $xp->query('//table[@class="precios"]')->item(0);

echo $doc->saveHTML($table);
```

Comment: Is this allowed? I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @Starx Well, it assumes that cross-domain issues are resolved ;-)

Comment: @cola89 Is the external page on another domain as your own page? If so, it won't work unless the external server explicitly allows it.

Comment: i put it in the title... IN AN EXTERNAL PAGE, ANOTHER DOMAIN!!

Comment: @cola89 You didn't say another domain. In any case, I've added a PHP example.

Comment: @Jack this is really awesome! but i have a little problem, in the echo appears a lot of Â symbols... do you know the meaning?

Comment: @cola89 That would be encoding issues; check the character sets of both your page and the external one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a AJAX request to that page and use `.find()` to get the element

```
$.ajax( {
  url: myUrl,
  success: function(html) {
    table = $(html).find(".precious");
    }
});
```

Comment: Wait, you can point it out with ajax to any url and get content of any element? WOW, didn't know that :)

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Well, you can't. Not without the "any server" giving you permissions :)

Comment: @Jack : Lol, I thought about that, but Starx's reputation blinded me :)

Comment: @MiljanPuzović, Common, every one knows about cross domain issues.

Comment: @Starx, I know, I know... but my mind is turning off, it's 4:30 AM here :)

Comment: @MiljanPuzović, Better sleep then Mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cURL (if installed) and make use of DOMDocument class in php